# send variable to $this->session->set_flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to upload image, and want to grab the errors in set_flashdata, in following code, unable to sent the error message as variable.

```
public function update_data($id)
{

$config['upload_path']   = "./school_folder/users_picture"; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
     $config['max_size']      = '2048'; 
     $config['max_width']     = '1024'; 
     $config['max_height']    = '768'; 
     $config['file_name'] = $id;
     $config['encrypt_name'] = false; 
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->overwrite = true;

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {       // in case of fuilure
// the following portion of code don't show the error message 

                    $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item',$error );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id);
                            }
            else // in case of success 
            {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'Successfully uploaded' );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id);


                }
```

here is debug of $error:

```
$error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
echo $error;
die();
```

it display the following:

> The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed
>   dimensions.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to show the error message, when redirected to view.

Comment: So did you check what $error contains, by making a debug output and commenting out the redirect …?

Comment: yes it has this error: The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have for showing the error, since that's what you're asking about.

Comment: the code is in Question. or you want to upload the complete code for image upload?

Comment: Is the complete code relevant for this current issue? You need to post all the relevant code for the _issue_ at hand. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: the code which making problem is included in Question. also included the error message debug.

Comment: the complete code is in Question now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please have a look into question, the complete function is included.

Comment: Yes, we can see you _setting_ the error and that it exists at that point, but you're still not showing us how you're _getting_ and _outputting_ the error (I don't mean the debug code, which is still in the same file). There's _nothing_ in the posted code that would suggest _"unable to sent the error message as variable"_. How and where did you determine that you can't send it?

Comment: // in case of fuilure

                    $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item',$error );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id);

Comment: this code don't send / show the error message, as sent as variable $error.

Comment: edited the Question with a // comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193523/discussion-between-muhammad-nadeem-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: Ok. Let's try this one last time. You state in your question that you're _"unable to sent the error message as variable"_. What **_exactly_** do you mean by that? All you're showing us is you getting the error using: `$error = $this->upload->display_errors()`. You're then debugging it: `echo $error;` and you say it contains what you expect: _"The image you are attempting to upload doesn't...."_. Then you're adding the error message as session flashdata and then you're redirecting the user. Where exactly is your issue?

Comment: the problem is that the error message which i am sending as $this->session->set_flashdata('item',$error );  is not displaying.

Comment: Why would it be displaying? You're not outputting anything anywhere?

Comment: if i try with text message, like  $this->session->set_flashdata('item','The file is not uploaded there is somthing wrong.' ); it shows.

Comment: But _where is the code that's outputting it_? It doesn't do that by itself. You _must_ have code somewhere that actually _outputs_ the string. Also, you're setting `error` in your code and your example is setting `item`. Those are two totally different keys.

Comment: $this->session->set_flashdata('item',$error );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id); the first line display something and the 2nd line redrirect to a view.

Comment: This is like pulling teeth. Since you completely _refuse_ to show us the code you're expecting to output the data (the code this question is _actually_ about), I'm out. I've also voted to close the question as "unclear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'Successfully uploaded');
```

view.php

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
    <div id="mydiv" class="alert alert-success"><?= $this->session->flashdata('category_success') ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
    ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**check this link**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkKvZ.png

Comment: $this->session->set_flashdata('item','There is somting wrong.' );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id); this will show the message.

Comment: $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item',$error );
redirect('index.php/Users/students_edit/'.$id);

Comment: but this is not showing what is in the variable $error

Comment: set_flashdata('item',$error) i am not using 2 different, that may be typo error.

Comment: <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('item')) { ?>
           <div id="mydiv" class="alert alert-success"><?= $this->session->flashdata('category_success') ?>
         <?php
            echo $this->session->flashdata('item');
         ?>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>

Comment: i just want to send the message as variable $error, nothing else, as I mentioned. i can display hard coded text message.

Comment: is there anything unclear? I want to display what is in $error, but unable to ...